# Word for resetting or recalibrating

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a more suitable word than *recalibrate* in my sentence below. I think the context of the word I'm looking for is clear here from the sentence.

> After spending years having a chummy relationship with my boss, the
> party incident forced us to *recalibrate* our relationship into
> something more formal.

[PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/recalibrate) provides over 250 synonyms (adjust, change, restore, revise, amend, change, remedy ...), but not all are equally appropriate here.

Bonus: Is there anything else stylistically or grammatically unsatisfactory with the sentence? It bothers me that I'm using the word *something*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not settle for *changed* which, as it turns out, is the stock word in such contexts?

*transmuted* and *toned down* are other alternatives you might like, but the former could sound a tad heavy in such a context.

As regards your sentence, I suggest that you rewrite it because it contains a *dangling participle*. It appears as if *the party incident* *has spent years of chummy relationship with your boss.* Thus perhaps, you could write—

> After years of a chummy relationship with my boss, I was forced to change our relationship into a formal one owing to the party incident.

> I was forced to tone down the chummy relationship with my boss,thanks to the party incident.

> **EDIT**— In response to the OP's comments, I am slightly expanding my answer. Since the OP wants the sentence to conjure in readers a sense of "quantifiable relationship", if you will, I suggest the phrasal verb *ratchet down*, which readily evokes this sense (*ratchet*, by the way, consists of a *toothed wheel and a bar* which governs motion; the phrasal verb furnishes the notion of *metaphorical motion*).

As regards the other query, *spending* for some reason didn't seem to sit well there. I may be wrong on this count but would certainly, either leave the word out or use *enjoy* instead because it collocates fluidly with *chummy relationship*.

Comment: 1) Thanks for your detailed response. I have a number of questions. (1) I'm looking for a verb in place of 'change' that evokes some sort of imagery in the mind of the reader - 'recalibrate' implies turning the dial on some parameters but keeping the same structure of the relationship largely in place which is why I don't think it fits the context of the sentence.

Comment: 2) I noticed you omitted the verb "spend" in your reconstituted sentence. Is that because it appeared superfluous? Want to know as I have a habit of bloating my writing with these 'fillers'.

Comment: 3) Besides the issue of the *dangling participle* is the use of *something* stylistically bad?

Comment: I have addressed  points 1) and 2) in the edited version of my answer. As for point 3), it is considered a grammatical error as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: Thanks I really like "rachet down" - it captures what I'm after. On a slightly more meta question - do you have any tips on how I can become more in tune with good stylistic constructions? I'm able to recognise better word constructions than I am able to deliver them.

Comment: @piccolo— I am afraid I may not be the best person to answer this question. I would love to be of some help here, but I am sure there are others hereabouts who could answer it better. :)

Answer (score 1):

My own feeling about your sentence is that *recalibrate* is a weirdly used piece of business jargon and that it should not be used in this context. It is often used to impress the listener (with a spurious impression of objectivity) rather than to inform them (about a subjective matter).

If ***re**calibrated*, how was friendship "*calibrated*" in the first place? Why apply a verb that relates to the comparison or setting of things on a numerical scale to an emotional thing such as friendship?

> calibrate = *to mark units of measurement on an instrument such so that it can measure accurately*
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calibrate)

> calibrate = *to standardize (something, such as a measuring instrument) by determining the deviation from a standard so as to ascertain the proper correction factors*
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calibrate

Comment: I come from a science background so it's illuminating to me that you referenced it as business jargon. We often deploy the word when we're working with some experimental setup where tuning one or more parameters might help us achieve an optimal solution or for the experiment to just work. I perceive relationships as parametrised by many factors that can be tuned. In the context of my example, I wanted to retune those factors to optimise for a new solution. I didn't use the word to try to seem pretentious - it's just the lens that I see things through. Does that make sense?

Comment: *where the "solution" is an ideal stable relationship between myself and my boss.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the various synonyms of 'change', 'realign' that various dictionaries and thesauruses offer, and the one I feel has the best connotations and register here is **re-evaluate**.

> *re-evaluate* [verb; I or T] (also reevaluate)
>
> to consider or examine something again in order to make changes or
> to form a new opinion about it:
>
> - *We have re-evaluated our mail order business with the aim of building on and* *upgrading*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/re-evaluate)]

It is commonly used for relationships:

> - *If you have set boundaries with this person and they continually violate your standards, it is time to reevaluate your relationship.*

[[Elaine Nilsson, Quora](https://www.quora.com/When-or-how-do-you-know-it-is-time-to-reevaluate-your-relationship-with-your-girlfriend-or-boyfriend)]

The 'consequent retailoring' is almost a given.

In your example sentence, 'opting for / agreeing on something more formal' say would be required.